# What Docusign Permission set a user needs in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We are integrating the Docusign e-signature within a salesforce org. the package provids Docusign Admin, User, sender and Login permission set.
if i would have a user that is a sender with a docusign account, which permission set is needed for him ?

When you install the DocuSign Apps Launcher package, a suite of DocuSign permission sets are added to the Salesforce organization.

Can soone explain for me what is the diffrence between both permission set Sender and user  ?
https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=izj1586134369853&topicId=xxm1623778416524.html&_LANG=enus

is the Docusign User enough for him or he needs the sender as well ?
because when checking the permission set, th user has more access then the sender.

it is not clear if we need to assign the sender or just the user permissionset to a docusign sender account.

Answer (score 1):

SF user with DS Sender permission: Send the envelope as a system sender. This user doesn't need to be a DocuSign user.

SF user with DS User permission: Send the envelope as themselves. This user has to be a DocuSign user.